# how can i add a hover on the nav, my way?

Tags: html, css, sass, header

I want to add an hover on the a element to show a round button but it takes the whole space of the li element instead of a big button in my navigation.

[`my codepen link`](http://codepen.io/amirhanif/pen/WpQpyo)

How can i do that and do i need to update this code in a way to make it how i want it to be like this[image: this is how i want the design to be]

Comment: already removed padding, the funny thing is that if i want to style the a it takes the width of the li that's not what i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the width of the li element so its not 100% / 5, but 80% / 5

CodePen Link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWVXYj?editors=1100.

Then add some padding to the li element.

```
li {
      width: calc(80% / 5);
      padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the logo a certain width and height if i resize browser

Comment: @amirhanif Yes, instead of using a `%` for the width and height, use exact pixels instead. e.g. `width: 50px; height: 50px;`. In your website case, you need to specify a width for this to work. Try adding `width: 150px;` to the `&.logo` class.

Comment: if i give it a static width and height, the nav not stay in the center anymore, do i need to give it a margin

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: block` from `#header a` and `#header a:hover` and change padding to `padding: 0 14px` for hovered a.

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWoREr)

Answer (score 1):

Just change display property of a tag from display: block to display: inline-block, same for :hover too

```
a {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    background: $main;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    &:hover {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```